# Joomla 3.0 multiply Column Category blog on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, blogs, categories, joomla3.0

Just putting together a blog with joomla 3.0 with a three column layout, works fine on all other browsers but internet explorer unless in compatibility mode.

Images in centre column do not resize and overlap other columns.

Not sure where to start to fix this, is it a joomla issue, bootstrap or is their something I can do in css.

Will upload images when I have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Yootheme theme for Joomla?
I had the same problem with the Moustache theme from Yootheme.
The problem is in there UiKit Framework.

I solved it by adding the folowing code in the textbox on the page:
Joomla Backend -> Extentions -> Templatemanager -> yoo_moustache (or your theme name) -> (scrolldown) "Additional Scripts"

```
<style>
.uk-article{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
a.uk-align-right>img{
    width:100%;
}
</style>
```

But you could also just edit the CSS files;
I browsed my site around but i couldn't find any unwanted side effects. But i suggest you do the same.

May it be that you are not using a Yootheme theme, then i still have something for you:

Internet Explorer has some trouble with adjusting the sizes of containers with floating elements in them.
So i suggest searching for floating items (such as you images or the A tags around them) and 
giving the surrounding container the next css properties:

```
width:100%;
overflow:auto;
```

Next you images will likely stay there origional size so you may want to give them a css property like:

```
width:100%;
```